# Cache html .load results for quicker loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, caching

I was wondering how do I cache results from the .load function in javascript, I'm loading a html file like the one below, what I want to be able to do is load the cache by Parent-ID then when each child-ID is called it doesn't have to reload the html file everytime.

```
<div id="provider1">

    <div id="thumb1">
content1
    </div>
    <div id="thumb2">
content2
    </div>
    <div id="thumb3">
content3
    </div>
</div>
```

And the javascript I've been using:

```
var titleID = $(this).attr('id');
$('#content').prepend('<div id="loading">load</div>')
.load('test.html #'+ titleID')
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajaxSetup ({
    cache: true
});

var titleID = $(this).attr('id');
$('#content').prepend('<div id="loading">load</div>')
.load('test.html #'+ titleID')
```

Comment: @user827570:  Please show your support by [accepting my answer via button showed on image](http://i.imgur.com/uqJeW.png)

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite load logic like this:

```
if (stuff in localStorage) {
// take it from there
} else {
// load
// on complete, put stuff in localStorage
}
```

Check http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/storage.html. There is also [jQuery.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/), you can do some simple caching with it too.